# How to multiply a vector in vector form by a scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Is this possible to do in linear algebra?
[image]

Comment: Sure; it's $\begin{bmatrix}-2tx_1\\-2tx_2\\-2-2t(x_3-1)\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was preventing you from solving this problem?

Comment: @littleO, just rusty. Was unsure which part of the vector was eligible for multiplication, the "stationary point" or the "direction", turns out both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
-2 \cdot \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
+ t \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3-1 \end{bmatrix} \right)
&= 
(-2) \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
+ (-2)t \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3-1 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -2 
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
-2tx_1 \\ -2tx_2 \\ -2tx_3 + 2t
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
-2tx_1 \\
-2tx_2 \\
-2 -2tx_3 + 2t
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*} 
$$